# Converting a string to array in javascript without eval()

Tags: javascript, web, cookies

I want to implement a counter for unique articles visited in my website, basically storing the ids of the articles the user has visited in a cookie. My issue is that the recovered value is, of course, a string. How would you convert a string that looks like this `"['test','b','c']"` to an array? Using eval is not advised, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to turn a string into an array:

```js
const string = '["test","b","c"]';
const arr = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Note that you need to have proper JSON formatting, though - keys and non-numeric values need to have *double* quotes. Easiest to serialize automatically with JSON.stringify:

```js
const arr = ["test","b","c"];
const str = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(str);
```

If you absolutely cannot change the single-quotes in the string you're working with originally, then use `replace` to turn it into something parseable:

```js
const str = "['test','b','c']";
const jsonFormattedStr = str.replace(/'/g, '"');
const arr = JSON.parse(jsonFormattedStr);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` won't work on the string provided by OP, though.

Comment: Right, which is why he should be using `JSON.stringify` to take care of the formatting problems automatically.

Comment: Not sure that makes sense. He said he can only get the array as a string initially. `JSON.stringify` is used to convert objects to strings, not cleanup formatting problems.

Comment: you could replace the `'` with `"` and then parse it (to work with the OP) `JSON.parse(string.replace(new RegExp('\'', 'g'), '"'));`

Comment: As I am also searching for a solution, sadly the `replace()` fails in `['test "one"','b','c']`

Answer (score 1):

While using `JSON.parse()` is the correct way to convert data strings to usable objects, the string in your question is not valid JSON syntax. Namely the single quotes will result in an `unexpected token` error.

If your only issue is the quotes, then it becomes trivial to prepare your data for parsing:

```js
var str = "['test','b','c']"
// convert to double quotes
str = str.split('\'').join('"')
// now parse
var arr = JSON.parse(str)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the quotes to double quotes, and then use JSON.parse

```
let string = "['test','b','c']";
// replace quotes with double quotes
let stringFixed = string.replace(/'/g, '"');
// parse the string
let result = JSON.parse( stringFixed );
```